# overflow-x not working on firefox; works on Chrome/edge

Tags: css, firefox, overflow

I'm trying to do dot leaders in a table cell. I've got it working on Chrome and on Edge, but Firefox isn't properly truncating the leader. Here is a cut-down version showing the problem. On Chrome/Edge, I see **1928.......|1,109|** correctly, while on Firefox the dots just keep going right over the next table cell and out the end.  (Firefox 50.1.0; Chrome 55.0.2883.87)
This is based on the example https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/leaders.en.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        td.leader-dots {
          max-width:40em;
          overflow-x:hidden;
          background:green;
        }
        td.leader-dots::after {
          float:left;
          width:0;
          white-space:nowrap;
          content: "..........................................................";
          background:red;
        }
        td.leader-dots span {
          background:yellow;
        }

        .tab1c1 { border-right: 1px solid black; }
        .tab1c2 { border-right: 1px solid black; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>   

    <table>
    <colgroup>
    <col span='1' style='width: 7em;'/>
    <col span='1' style='width: 0em;'/>
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td class='tab1c1 leader-dots'><span>1928</span></td>
        <td class='tab1c2'>1,109</td>
    </tr>
    </table>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `td.leader-dots` to `display: block;` (the `float` on `::after` is making it trip):

```css
td.leader-dots {
  max-width: 40em;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: block;
  background: green;
}
td.leader-dots::after {
  float: left;
  width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  content: "..........................................................";
  background: red;
}
td.leader-dots span {
  background: yellow;
}
.tab1c1 {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
.tab1c2 {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col span='1' style='width: 7em;' />
    <col span='1' style='width: 0em;' />
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td class='tab1c1 leader-dots'><span>1928</span>
    </td>
    <td class='tab1c2'>1,109</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Tested in latest firefox:
[image]

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks. Is this a firefox bug, or a looseness in the specification?

Comment: Since the element after is floating it doesn't behave according to dimensions therefore doesn't know when to prevent overflowing.

Answer (score 0):

Change `overflow-x:hidden;` in `td.leader-dots` to **`overflow`**`:hidden;`, just as the example you provided.

It worked on Firefox, Chrome, and MS Edge, when I tested it.